# How can one adapt the "\newstylepage" command?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

How can one adapt the `\newstylepage` command in order to change its behaviour depending on which page you are?

I'm using the `article` template, creating new pages every time I start a new section - with the package `titlesec`, by using the following new command `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}`.

I'm also changing the header, by using the package `titleps` through the following lines of code

```
\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \setheadrule{1pt}%
    \sethead[][][\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle] % Par
            {\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{} % Ímpar
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]%
            {}{\thepage}{}
}
```

What I want to do is using the stylized new header ONLY on that pages in which I'm NOT initiating a new section. How can I do that?

In other words, I want to remove this new header when I'm on a page which corresponds to a new section.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

As suggested on the comments, here a small self-contained example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titleps} 

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \setheadrule{1pt}%
    \sethead[][][\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle]%
    {\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{}%
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]%
    {}{\thepage}{}
}

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \pagestyle{main}

    \section{Section A}

    \subsection{Sub-section I}

    Text.

    \subsection{Sub-section II}

    LOREM IPSUM text.

    \section{Section B}

    \subsection{Sub-section I}

    Text.

\end{document}
```

To exemplify it a little bit more, here are two images - the first one is what I want to change, and the second one is what I want to preserve:

[image: NOT OK]

[image: OK]

Comment: As always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full, but minimal, self contained document that others can copy and test as is.]

Comment: @daleif, thank you for your suggestion, it's done now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\thispagestyle{plain}` to the `\sectionbreak` command.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titleps} 

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain}}% <- changed

\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \setheadrule{1pt}%
    \sethead[][][\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle]%
    {\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{}%
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]%
    {}{\thepage}{}
}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{main}
\section{Section A}
\subsection{Sub-section I}
\lipsum
\subsection{Sub-section II}
\lipsum
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Sub-section I}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, thank you!